# Side by side video not showing properly on fire tv app

Tags: javascript, html, viewport, amazon-fire-tv

I was trying to create a firetv [HTML5 web app](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/platforms/webapps/docs/getting-started-with-web-apps-for-fire-tv) with the bellow code,

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang='en'>
    <head>
    <title>
      FireTV
    </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta id="viewport"  name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script>
        var vp = document.getElementById('viewport');
        var initialScale = Math.max(screen.width, screen.height)/1920;

        vp.setAttribute('content','width=device-width, initial-scale=' + initialScale + ', maximum-scale=' + initialScale, + 'minimum-scale=' + initialScale);


    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
    <video>
      <source src="sbsmovie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
 </body>
 </html>
```

The video is playing well on my amazon fireTV,but the problem is ,When i turn on 3D mode on my tv,there is  a gap on both sides.Is it possible to prevent this?

Here is the output i got on my 3d tv.The issue of display is shown in red boxes.

[image]